# Open a document with Objective-C for an OS X application

Tags: objective-c, macos, file, cocoa

I've implemented a simple application that basically outputs informations about a given triangle (see image). I've created the triangles programmatically. I would like to improve this example providing a mechanism to open a say .tri file with its sides (e.g. 3 4 5). How can I achieve that ? I've done some research and found out there's a method called openDocument.. How would I use this on my application ? Can someone give me an example of how to achieve that ? Apparently it's not a document-based  application.. I've got this code on github: https://github.com/mcand/TableViewMacExample.

[image: Current Application]

Comment: What should I search for ? Should I implement my own function to open the file or use the openDocument function ? I've tried searching at the API but I didn't understand very well..

Comment: When I declare this method: - (IBAction)openDocument:(id)sender{

} I get the open menu to appear but nothing happens..

Comment: I managed to make the Panel appears like this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening the file, I cannot change the values of my NSTableView. The code is like that:

```
- (IBAction)openDocument:(id)sender{
    NSOpenPanel* panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [panel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tri", @"qua",nil]];

    [panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
            NSURL*  file = [[panel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];

            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(triangle:) withObject:file];

        }

    }];
}


-(void) triangle:(NSURL *)file{

        NSError *error;

        NSString *words = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

        NSLog(@"%@", words);

        NSArray* lines = [words componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

        NSMutableArray *shapes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        while (lines) {

            NSArray*info = [words componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

            // Creates triangles to be populated
            CGFloat side1 = (CGFloat)[info[0] floatValue];
            CGFloat side2 = (CGFloat)[info[1] floatValue];
            CGFloat side3 = (CGFloat)[info[2] floatValue];

            Triangle *triangle = [[Triangle alloc] initWithSides:side1 side:side2 andSide:side3];

            [shapes addObject:triangle];
        }

        self.formsArray = shapes;

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTableView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

}

-(void)updateTableView{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

Comment: The project is on my github. Hope anyone can help me https://github.com/mcand/TableViewMacExample.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make the panel appear like below.

```
- (IBAction)openDocument:(id)sender{
    NSOpenPanel* openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    [openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tri", @"qua",nil]];
    [openPanel runModal];

}
```

Comment: ... also consider 
`-beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:` if the thing being opened is going to end up in a particular existing window rather than being opened as something new.